# Using two similar tables or flags for many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I recently came across a project where I want to add some apps into a database. Every app has additional information that comes in a 1:1, 1:n or n:m relationship. Though I know how to store such relationships, I had some trouble with the developer(s) / publisher(s) for each app.

**The situation:**

- several thousand apps
- each app has its own id
- several thousand companies
- each company (developer/publisher) has its own id
- each app can have 0, 1 or multiple developers
- each app can have 0, 1 or multiple publishers
- each developer can have 1 or multiple apps
- each publisher can have 1 or multiple apps

It's pretty obvious that this is a many-to-many relationship and thus requires a junction table. Unfortunately, there are at least two viable options.

company

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
 `id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(I merged developers and publishers in this table, because a developer can also be a publisher and vice versa. I think this is better than having redundancy in two separate tables, isn't it?)

---

**Option 1:**

The first option would be to create two separate tables.

app_developer

```
CREATE TABLE `app_developer` (
 `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `app_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `company_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

app_publisher

```
CREATE TABLE `app_publisher` (
 `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `app_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `company_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Option 2:**

The second option would be to create a single table and add flags (0/1) for each app/company combination.

```
CREATE TABLE `app_company_rel` (
 `id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `app_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `company_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `developer` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `publisher` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

I don't know if there will be the requirement to search all apps from a specific developer/publisher in the future or if it's just an additional information without further purpose.

Which option would be better (in terms of consistency, redundancy, performance) or is there no considerable difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your first option will be very much efficient.  Storing in two different table is actually good. Create two tables and use app_id as foreign key. Storing in two different table makes data very clear and data retrieval will also be very easy and faster. Any doubt let me know, will explain you clearly

Answer (score 0):

Option 3:  Like #2, but with an `ENUM` or `SET` for dev and pub.

I would consider either Option 1 or Option 3.  But I would *not* include an `id` for a simple many-to-many mapping table; it slows things down.

[*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) and tips on how to write an optimal many-to-many table.

Comment: How would an `enum` be better than `tinyint(1)`? Since every combination of app/company can be 1/0, 0/1 or 1/1, I thought `tinyint(1)` for true/false would be preferred here. However, I agree with removing the `id`, as it's not necessary - I just forgot to remove it from the schema.

Comment: `ENUM('developer', 'publisher', ...)` - perhaps there will be a 3rd category?

Comment: Don't forget to add a `PRIMARY KEY` and a secondary index.

Comment: But `ENUM('developer', 'publisher', ...)` would not work if a company is developer and publisher at the same time. I guess I'd prefer option #1 then and use `PRIMARY KEY ('app_id','company_id'), INDEX ('company_id','app_id')`. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Then use `SET` instead of `ENUM`.  Anyway, it was just a "suggestion", not a "strong recommendation".

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is headed the right way. But this establishes not only the relationship between a company and a project but also the type of relationship -- developer or publisher.

```
create table ProjCompany(
    ProjID    int not null references Projects( ID ),
    CompanyID int not null references Company( ID ),
    TypeID    char( 1 ) not null references Types( ID ), -- 'D' or 'P'
    constraint OK_ProjCompany primary key( ProjID, CompanyID, TypeID )
);
```

A project can have each company listed as a developer only once but the same company could also show up as a publisher. A company could be a developer and/or publisher for any number of projects.

If any table needed a FK reference to a particular developer of a particular project, it would reference this table with the project id, the company id and the flag for developer. If that company was not defined as a developer for that project, the reference would be rejected.

Further, I would recommend a view that would show each project and their developers and a view that would show each project and their publishers. This would come in handy for portions of code that would be working only with developers or only with publishers.